# How to determine I2C Master timing parameters

Tags: i2c, timing

I am relatively new to I2C, but I have done much reading on the topic and I am confused as to the timing parameters necessary when designing an I2C Master.

I know of this chart from the [manual](http://www.nxp.com/documents/user_manual/UM10204.pdf) on page 48.
[image: Timing chart]

However it gives a large range of possible values.

For example, I need to set the following parameters for my I2C Master (using a National Instruments program) in Standard-Mode:

```
tSU;STA - MIN = 4700 ns
tHD;STA - MIN = 4000 ns
tSU;DAT - MIN = 250 ns
tHD;DAT - MIN = 0 ns
tSU;STO - MIN = 4000 ns
tBUF - MIN = 4700 ns
tHIGH - MIN = 4000 ns
fSCL - MIN = 0 - MAX = 100 kHz
```

How can I calculate the appropriate values for my I2C bus for all of the above?

Do you always use the minimum, does it matter how many slave devices there are, etc?

Comment: If you want to design robust systems, you design to meet the WORST CASE.  Sometimes that's minimum, and sometimes its a maximum.  Often, data sheets will give you the worst case (either in the minimum or maximum column, whichever applies), and a "typical value", which is best ignored!

Comment: Well I am using a National Instruments PXI machine to behave as the Master (this is the part I need the timing for).  The device I am communicating with is a MEMs gyroscope.  The data sheet for the gyroscope slave simply lists a copy of the above chart for Standard-Mode I2C as well.  Does that mean any values would work?  Its just hard for me to conceptualize changing a bunch of those numbers and expecting the same result.

Comment: The info on the data sheet should certainly override any information in the I2C standard you've posted from, as there is no real guarantee that the device actually meets the standard (often, the devices might even function BETTER than the standard calls for).  That said, I2C is pretty easy to use.  Devices can even fix things on their own using clock stretching if the master is trying to go too fast.  Pick numbers that looks reasonable, try them, and see if you get expected behavior.  It's not like you're carving them in stone.

Comment: Well I mainly ask because I would ideally like to use a smaller frequency on the clock.  If I set the fSCL to say 20 kHz.  I wouldn't need to adjust any other numbers?  I want to adhere to this statement from the manual: "here are several strategies
available to system designers to cope with
excess bus capacitance.  1. reduce fSCL"

Comment: Going slower on the clock should not require adjustment of other numbers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typically, an I2C slave device will work with any master which is no faster than what it is expecting.  In some cases there may be problems if the master is too slow, but those are generally only an issue if the master is *really* slow (e.g. taking multiple seconds to do something which would normally take under a millisecond).  Generally, the I2C spec says that for something to be a proper I2C slave it must be able to accommodate a certain speed, and that masters are entitled to assume that I2C devices will be able to either accommodate that speeds or add handshaking to tell the master to slow down.

Any typical off-the-shelf I2C slave should conform to the minimum standards for its specified speed, and any typical off-the-shelf device acting as an I2C master should work with any device that conforms to the standards associated with its specified speed.  Microcontrollers programmed to act as I2C slaves may not always conform to expected timings (their ability to do so depends in large measure on the firmware installed), but most other slave devices shouldn't pose any problem.